# changing projection hides raster

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

I have a map georeferenced in georeferecer plugin in QGIS. I have loaded it in qgis. It shows strangely (wrong aspect ratio than I expect). I am changing projection (bottom right "OTF" projection) from "Gauss Kruger zone4, to WGS).  This first results to change of position of the window to some ridiculous coordinates, after I find my original coordinates I see matched points but I see no raster. Why?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Your coordinates in the first picture are lon/lat. Are you sure the raster is georeferenced in GK? If it's really is lon/lat but the coordinates were treated as GK, that would explain the odd coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

If you have read the coordinates from the imprinted degree grid, you should have taken `EPSG:4178 Pulkovo 1942(83)` as target CRS. This is the geographic CRS behind EPSG:2398.

You can try `Set Layer CRS` to change it, or do the georeferencing again.